# Cómo puedo convertir este código PDO en Mysqli?

Tags: mysqli, pdo

Quiero convertir este código PDO en MySQLi, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
function usuario_por_codigo($CodUsua)
{
    $con = conexion("root", "");
    $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where CodUsua = :CodUsua");
    $consulta->execute(array(':CodUsua' => $CodUsua));
    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
    return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: Debería ser bastante directo, ¿con qué problemas te estás encontrando? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Es que yo solamente quiero convertir ese código PDO a Mysqli porque no domino mucho el PDO y esa es una función que necesito para mi proyecto y es exactamente la misma

Comment: No tendría caso regresar en cuanto a seguridad y buenas prácticas de programación de `PDO` a `Mysql` en todo caso **recomendaría aprender PDO**

Comment: _No camines para atrás_, PDO es mucho más recomendable que MySQLi, y además, **mucho más fácil**, lo único es que PDO hay que saberlo configurar bien. Aquí te dejo una [clase ya hecha: PHP-PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO), verás lo fácil que es hacer las cosas con PDO. Puedes usar esa clase si lo deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo mismo de la función en MySQLi es asi:

```
function conexion($usuario, $contraseña)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $usuario, $contraseña, "basededatos");

    // Compruebar la conexión
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    return $mysqli;
}

function usuario_por_codigo($CodUsua)
{
    $resultado = array();
    $con = conexion("root", "");
    $consulta = sprintf("select * from usuarios where CodUsua = '%s'", $CodUsua);
    if ($consulta = $con->query($consulta)) {
        while ($fila = $consulta->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($resultado, $fila);
        }

        $consulta->free();
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda si me sirvio de mucho

Comment: @CarlosSaz sí la respuesta ayudó  a solucionar sus dudas y/o inconvenientes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres cambiar a MySQLi, ¡si es mucho más complicado que pDO!, nada más tiene que comparar los dos códigos para verlo. Y hay otros usos en los que MySQLi es mucho más complicado o necesita drivers adicionales.

Comment: bueno gracias por el consejo